# Does using an unstable sort multiple times produce the same result for a dataset?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

Heapsort is an unstable sort. Does using it on different machines with the same dataset guarantee the same order in the resulting dataset even if it is unstable?

Edit: The implementation is C++ STL heap_sort running on different machines.

Comment: Do you mean a separate implementation of heapsort, or running the exact same one on multiple machines?

Comment: There is no guarantee it will run the same way on the same machine. It could depend on the phase of the moon for all I know.

Comment: Regardless, you should not be depending on such *undocumented* implementation details for the correctness of your code! That is the bottom line, in my opinion!

Comment: I am using the C++ STL implementation on multiple machines with the same architecture.

Answer (score 4):

If you provide the same input to the same implementation it will output the same result. This is called "determinism".

The only exception however is, if the algorithm is randomized (i.e. sampling/shuffling algorithms or [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)). You can mitigate that too by providing the same seed to the (pseudo) random number generator, but Heapsort is not a randomized algorithm anyway, so the result should be the same.

Stability in sorting refers to the guarantee that if you sort on a subset of all attributes, you will always get the same ordering with respect to all attributes. [I found the example on Wikipedia quite intuitive:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_halgorithm#Stability)

> When sorting some kinds of data, only part of the data is examined
>   when determining the sort order. For example, in the card sorting
>   example to the right, the cards are being sorted by their rank, and
>   their suit is being ignored. The result is that it's possible to have
>   multiple different correctly sorted versions of the original list.
>   Stable sorting algorithms choose one of these, according to the
>   following rule: if two items compare as equal, like the two 5 cards,
>   then their relative order will be preserved, so that if one came
>   before the other in the input, it will also come before the other in
>   the output.

To summarize: if the input to the same deterministic algorithm stays the same, you will definitely get the same result.

Just to add a small definition to "same input". The order of the input must still be the same. Example:

```
 Input 1: 2 1 3 5 4 3
 Input 2: 5 4 3 2 1 3
```

Sorting those two lists will give you the same result in their primary attribute:

```
 Result: 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

In the unstable case however, it is not guaranteed that the 3's are in the same sequence (when looking at other attributes attached) afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the algorithm is deterministic (Heapsort or any such algorithm) running it on different machines will guarantee the same output.

Comment: HOWEVER, if you run HeapSort provided by AcmeCollectionsLibrary 1.0, and HeapSort provided by AcmeCollectionsLibrary 2.0, say, there is no guarantee that the implementation will stay the same between the two versions!

Comment: That realistically applies to any implementation

Comment: @RobinGreen, That's due to implementation details. I assumed OP was talking about running the exact same implementation.

Comment: well of course, he or she may INTEND for that to be the case, but then some maintenance programmer updates the version of a dependency (intentionally or not), and then BOOM! it breaks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question, "Does using an unstable sort multiple times produce the same result for a dataset?" is an emphatic no in the general case. Consider a median-of-random-three Quicksort implementation. That's going to give you a different partitioning every time, so it's a quite likely that run twice against the same data set will give different ordering for equal values.

Heap sort probably should be deterministic. But I wouldn't count on it unless it was documented.